# Autofilter for dates error: "Method of Range Class Failed"

Tags: excel, vba, filter, autofilter

I have a macro to filter a sales report. It has been working for over a year. It stopped working. Nothing in the report changed.

I am getting an error at the autofilter line. I am trying to filter 3 criteria values in one field (3 dates).

I tried to record a macro filtering the report. When I run it I get

> Runtime error: 1004 "AutoFilter method of Range class failed".

Here is the recorded line below, I had changed some of the values in my code to have variables instead of hardcoding but I posted this for testing purpose.  I made sure the report is not filtered before trying to autofilter.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "2/5/2021", 2, "2/6/2021", 2, "2/7/2021")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:= xlFilterValues, _
  Criteria1:=Array("2/5/2021", "2/6/2021", "2/7/2021")
```

note `Criteria1` not `Criteria2`

[image]

EDIT: FYI I was not aware of this at all but this link https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/filter-dates/ explains the syntax you got from the macro recorder - it's about filtering date "groups" rather than specific dates (see "Multiple Date Groups").

Comment: I have tried it like this and it didn't work either, when I record it, it will appear with Criteria2 instead of 1, and will add the "2"'s inside the array, but I have tried it like you have it above changing those two things and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Worked fine for me, but I don't have access to your data for testing.

Comment: @SenorPenguin If the cells contain real (numeric) date values try to use numeric values unstead of strings in your filter array: `CDbl(DateSerial(2021, 2, 5))` where `DateSerial(Year, Month, Day)`.

Comment: @TimWilliams I know it works because it was working for me for a year, I'm trying to figure out why it would stop working

Comment: If it stopped working then *something* changed - we only know as much about your environment as you've included in your post, so all we can do is test what you outlined and report back...  Unless you can share a non-working example there's not much else I could suggest to try.

Comment: @TimWilliams I got it, I had to format the date to match the search value format before filtering, it worked before without but thanks for confirming it was just me!